# How to retrieve signed pdf document from docusign webhook response?

Tags: docusignapi

I can't see signed document attachment anywhere in webhook's response. I am getting below response on signing completed:

[image]

- Is there anything I need to configure for getting signed pdf document in webhook's response?
- Is there any response model available to parse response into?
- Is the xml format is fixed while getting webhook response or we can configure to other type also?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set it first in your webhook settings.
Select Include -> "Document PDFs".
In your webhook message body you should see

```
    <DocumentPDFs>
        <DocumentPDF>
            <Name>Lorem Ipsum</Name>
            <PDFBytes>.........</PDFBytes>
            <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
            <DocumentType>CONTENT</DocumentType>
        </DocumentPDF>
    </DocumentPDFs>
```

Comment: Is 'DocumentPDFs' contains multiple 'DocumentPDF' tags if we have multiple documents on a docusign template ? I have a template that contains 7 documents and I want to store signed documents Individually in my system.

Comment: The best way is to try